# Read query result by column name in SQLite Nativescript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nativescript

I've been working with **nativescript-sqlite** plugin for a while. I'm selecting data from my tables which works fine. I would like to access this data by my table's column names and this is where the challenge begins.

```
viewModel.selectAllRecords = function () {
    new sqlite("etudiz.db", function (err, db) {
        db.all("SELECT post_title,post_cat FROM posts ORDER BY id", [],  function (tableErr, rs) {                    
            var ObjLength = rs.length;
            var i = 0;
            for(i >= 0; i<ObjLength; i++) {
                console.log(rs[i]['post_title']) //This is undefined
                console.log(rs[i][0])//This is working well
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I prefer reading the data by column names rather than 0,1,2....etc. Is there a work-around or is that how SQLite is designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite) says:

> **DB.resultType()**
>
> Parameters
>
> - Pass in `Sqlite.RESULTSASOBJECT` or `Sqlite.RESULTSASARRAY` to change the result sets configuration This will set the database to return the results in which ever choice you make. (Default is `RESULTSASARRAY`)

> `Sqlite.RESULTSASARRAY` - Returns results as Arrays (ex: `select name, phone` --- results `[[name,phone]]`)
>   `Sqlite.RESULTSASOBJECT` - Returns results as Objects (ex: `select name, phone` --- results `[{name: name, phone: phone}]`